# How do I properly set up a Gruntfile.js that will be compatible with a custom Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, gruntjs

I am starting to dabble a little with Grunt and it has truly become a game changer for me. I've used it on small little projects just to test how it works and also to try out all of the different npm packages that make Grunt so great. Well I am a Wordpress developer by nature and I am starting to combine Grunt and Wordpress but am running into some difficulties since Grunt is still fairly new to me. I was wondering how to properly set up a Gruntfile.js that would be compatible with a custom Wordpress site. What I mean by this... is I need Grunt to run all of my different packages such as browser-sync, watch, and so on but with a Wordpress site. Documentation on this topic is very hard to come by so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

I have had success with plain html sites but a common error that I am getting when trying it with my Wordpress site is 'Cannot GET /' when I launch grunt through my command prompt...

Below is my current Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
 grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
   sass: {
    dist: {
    files: {
    'style.css' : 'style.scss'
      }
     }
    },
    watch: {
    css: {
    files: '**/*.scss',
    tasks: ['sass']
     }
    },
    browserSync: {
    default_options: {
    bsFiles: {
    src: [
    "style.css",
    "*.php"
    ]
   },
    options: {
    files: ['style.css', 'js/**/*.js', '**/*.php'],
    watchTask: true,
    server: {
    baseDir: "./"
    }
    }
   }
  }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.registerTask('default',['browserSync','watch']);
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be structured in the exact same way as the smaller projects you've done, but in a theme folder in wp-content/themes/your-theme. BrowserSync is essentially a proxy so doesn't matter what system you're using, it should work.